# Different colours for different articles using a:hover

Tags: php, wordpress, hover, onhover

I'm trying to assign three different colours to three different articles on a single page using `a:hover` in Wordpress.

This is the site <del>http://paragrams.wpshower.com/</del>

At present all the articles turn pale yellow on `a:hover`. I'm trying to create different colours for each article (for example, first article to be yellow, the second article red, third blue and so on).

Below is the php & CSS for the `a:hover` at present. I assume I need to wrap each thumb id in a different div and specify the colour in the CSS?

PHP:

```
<ul class="mcol">
          <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li class="article">

                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <?php 
                    $imgsrcparam = array(
                    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $post-    >post_excerpt )),
                    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $post-    >post_title )),
                    );
                    $thumbID = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'background',     $imgsrcparam ); ?>



                    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="preview"><?php echo     "$thumbID"; ?></a></div>
                    <?php } ?>


                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

and CSS:

```
.li_container {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url(images/main-bg.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: left top;
}
.li_container .article:hover {
background-color:#57bfeb;
}
```

This is the js:

```
  #  * Splits a <ul>/<ol>-list into equal-sized columns. 
#  *  
#  * Requirements:  
#  * <ul> 
#  * <li>"ul" or "ol" element must be styled with margin</li> 
#  * </ul> 
#  *  
#  * @see http://www.codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery 
#  */  
jQuery.fn.makeacolumnlists = function(settings){
settings = jQuery.extend({
    cols: 3,                // set number of columns
    colWidth: 0,            // set width for each column or leave 0 for     auto width
    equalHeight: 'li',  // can be false, 'ul', 'ol', 'li'
    startN: 1               // first number on your ordered list
}, settings);

if(jQuery('> li', this)) {
    this.each(function(y) {
        var y=jQuery('.li_container').size(),
            height = 0, 
            maxHeight = 0,
            t = jQuery(this),
            classN = t.attr('class'),
            listsize = jQuery('> li', this).size(),
            percol = Math.ceil(listsize/settings.cols),
            contW = t.width(),
            bl = ( isNaN(parseInt(t.css('borderLeftWidth'),10)) ? 0 :     parseInt(t.css('borderLeftWidth'),10) ),
            br = ( isNaN(parseInt(t.css('borderRightWidth'),10)) ? 0 :     parseInt(t.css('borderRightWidth'),10) ),
            pl = parseInt(t.css('paddingLeft'),10),
            pr = parseInt(t.css('paddingRight'),10),
            ml = parseInt(t.css('marginLeft'),10),
            mr = parseInt(t.css('marginRight'),10),
            col_Width = Math.floor((contW - (settings.cols-1)*(bl+br+pl+pr+ml+mr))/settings.cols);
        if (settings.colWidth) {
            col_Width = settings.colWidth; 
        }
        var colnum=1,
            percol2=percol;
        jQuery(this).addClass('li_cont1').wrap('<div id="li_container' + (++y) + '" class="li_container"></div>');
        for (var i=0; i<=listsize; i++) {
            if (colnum > settings.cols) colnum = 1;
            var eq = jQuery('> li:eq('+i+')',this);
            eq.addClass('li_col'+colnum);
            colnum++;
            //if(i>=percol2) { percol2+=percol; colnum++; }
            //var eq = jQuery('> li:eq('+i+')',this);
            //eq.addClass('li_col'+ colnum);
            //if(jQuery(this).is('ol')){eq.attr('value', ''+(i+settings.startN))+'';}
        }
        jQuery(this).css({cssFloat:'left', width:''+col_Width+'px'});
        for (colnum=2; colnum<=settings.cols; colnum++) {
            if(jQuery(this).is('ol')) {
                jQuery('li.li_col'+ colnum, this).appendTo('#li_container' + y).wrapAll('<ol class="li_cont'+colnum +' ' + classN + '" style="float:left; width: '+col_Width+'px;"></ol>');
            } else {
                jQuery('li.li_col'+ colnum, this).appendTo('#li_container' + y).wrapAll('<ul class="li_cont'+colnum +' ' + classN + '" style="float:left; width: '+col_Width+'px;"></ul>');
            }
        }
        if (settings.equalHeight=='li') {
            for (colnum=1; colnum<=settings.cols; colnum++) {
                jQuery('#li_container'+ y +' li').each(function() {
                    var e = jQuery(this);
                    var border_top = ( isNaN(parseInt(e.css('borderTopWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(e.css('borderTopWidth'),10) );
                    var border_bottom = ( isNaN(parseInt(e.css('borderBottomWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(e.css('borderBottomWidth'),10) );
                    height = e.height() + parseInt(e.css('paddingTop'), 10) + parseInt(e.css('paddingBottom'), 10) + border_top + border_bottom;
                    maxHeight = (height > maxHeight) ? height : maxHeight;
                });
            }
            for (colnum=1; colnum<=settings.cols; colnum++) {
                var eh = jQuery('#li_container'+ y +' li');
                var border_top = ( isNaN(parseInt(eh.css('borderTopWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(eh.css('borderTopWidth'),10) );
                var border_bottom = ( isNaN(parseInt(eh.css('borderBottomWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(eh.css('borderBottomWidth'),10) );
                mh = maxHeight - (parseInt(eh.css('paddingTop'), 10) + parseInt(eh.css('paddingBottom'), 10) + border_top + border_bottom );
                eh.height(mh);
            }
        } else 
        if (settings.equalHeight=='ul' || settings.equalHeight=='ol') {
            for (colnum=1; colnum<=settings.cols; colnum++) {
                jQuery('#li_container'+ y +' .li_cont'+colnum).each(function() {
                    var e = jQuery(this);
                    var border_top = (     isNaN(parseInt(e.css('borderTopWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(e.css('borderTopWidth'),10) );
                    var border_bottom = ( isNaN(parseInt(e.css('borderBottomWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(e.css('borderBottomWidth'),10)     );
                    height = e.height() + parseInt(e.css('paddingTop'),     10) + parseInt(e.css('paddingBottom'), 10) + border_top + border_bottom;
                    maxHeight = (height > maxHeight) ? height :     maxHeight;
                });
            }
            for (colnum=1; colnum<=settings.cols; colnum++) {
                var eh = jQuery('#li_container'+ y +'     .li_cont'+colnum);
                var border_top = (     isNaN(parseInt(eh.css('borderTopWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(eh.css('borderTopWidth'),10) );
                var border_bottom = ( isNaN(parseInt(eh.css('borderBottomWidth'),10)) ? 0 : parseInt(eh.css('borderBottomWidth'),10) );
                mh = maxHeight - (parseInt(eh.css('paddingTop'), 10) + parseInt(eh.css('paddingBottom'), 10) + border_top + border_bottom );
                /*eh.height(mh);*/
            }
        }
        jQuery('#li_container' + y).append('<div style="clear:both; overflow:hidden; height:0px;"></div>');
    });
}
}

jQuery.fn.uncolumnlists = function(){
jQuery('.li_cont1').each(function(i) {
    var onecolSize = jQuery('#li_container' + (++i) + ' .li_cont1 > li').size();
    if(jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' .li_cont1').is('ul')) {
        jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' > ul > li').appendTo('#li_container'     + i + ' ul:first');
        for (var j=1; j<=onecolSize; j++) {
            jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' ul:first li').removeAttr('class').removeAttr('style');
        }
        jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' ul:first').removeAttr('style').removeClass('li_cont1').insertBefore('#li_container' + i);
    } else {
        jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' > ol > li').appendTo('#li_container' + i + ' ol:first');
        for (var j=1; j<=onecolSize; j++) {
            jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' ol:first li').removeAttr('class').removeAttr('style');
        }
        jQuery('#li_container' + i + ' ol:first').removeAttr('style').removeClass('li_cont1').insertBefore('#li_container' + i);
    }
    jQuery('#li_container' + i).remove();
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't need to do anything fancy with divs; just give each `li` tag a unique class, and specify those class colors in css.

From your code, you could change the line

```
<li class="article">
```

to

```
<?php
switch($post->ID) {
    case 1:
        $class = 'yellow';    break;
    case 2:
        $class = 'blue';      break;
    case 3:
        $class = 'green';     break;
}
?>
<li class="article <?php echo $class; ?>">
```

This will effectively output `class='article yellow'` for the first article, `class='article blue'` for the second, etc. You can then make this all work by changing the css as follows:

```
.li_container .article.yellow:hover { background-color:#57bfeb; }
.li_container .article.green:hover  { background-color:green; }
.li_container .article.blue:hover   { background-color:blue; }
```

If you want to get fancy, you could also change `switch($post->ID)` to `switch(mod($post->ID,3))` to do lots of color changing.

Comment: @user557318 - sorry, actually checked your page and realized that you want to style the `li` tag, not the `a`. Fixed it up a bit.

Comment: @eykanal i've tried changing the php as suggested but it just blank screened the site completely?

Comment: The li tag change made the site back to normal but it now simply has no :hover class at all, just stays white

Comment: @user557318 - fixed, remove the space between `.article` and `.(color)`. It should be all one phrase, `.article.yellow:hover`. Also, do note that IE doesn't support `:hover` on non-`a` tags. Do a search on how to work around that.

Comment: @eykanal there still seems to be no :hover class being applied on the links just plain white surround, no color rollovers at all ? sorry to pester you but your method seems less complex (which is ideal for me) than toodles but i still can't get it to work ?

Comment: @user557318 - I don't know how much more help I can give. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eykanal/a4Uqg/)... it may give you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

eykanal has a good solution. Just to throw out another option, you could use jquery and just dynamically add the classes based on the article positions in the dom. Something like:

Add this inside the head element of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mcol li.article:nth-child(1)').addClass('yellow')
    $('.mcol li.article:nth-child(2)').addClass('red')
    $('.mcol li.article:nth-child(3)').addClass('blue') 
  });
</script>
```

You would then add something like this to your css file:

```
.yellow:hover { background-color: yellow; }
.red:hover { background-color: red; }
.blue:hover { background-color: blue; }
```

Change the colors to the hex codes of your choice of course.
Have Fun!

Comment: thanks @toddles2000 . All the although they have changed to pure yellow are still the same colour ?

Comment: Your css rules indicates that you have a class called li_container though in the source above we only see '<ul class="mcol">'. Perhaps you should change all references in the javascript to use it instead.

Comment: @toddles2000 sorry for all the questions. . . . Ive added the js above. Which refrences woud it be ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your actual source code. Perhaps this your css class issue is related to the problem you are having with the other answer as well.

Comment: @toddles2000 basically only the first line of the three in css is being applied to all the links. so when i put in     .yellow:hover { background-color: yellow; } all links are yellow, If i was to change the color: 
 to say blue on the top line all three links are blue ?? any ideas

Comment: Please look closely at the fiddler that eykanal sent you. The basic problem you seem to be having with both answers is your css selectors apparently aren't aligning with your actual html.

Answer (score 0):

What i'd personally do is add an incrementing class using PHP, like so..

```
<ul class="mcol">
<?php if(have_posts()) : $i = 0; while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $i++; ?>
    <li class="article <?php echo "item-$i";?>">
```

You then get something like..

```
<li class="article item-1">content</li>
<li class="article item-2">content</li>
<li class="article item-3">content</li>
```

Then toggle a class on hover to..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.article').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active-item');
    });
});
```

That then gives you one class that covers all list items, one unique to each item shown, and one that is only attached to the element on hover..

```
li.article { /* CSS for all list items */ }
li.article.active-item { /* CSS for all any item active */ }
li.item-1 { /* CSS for the first item */ }
li.item-2 { /* CSS for the second item */ }
li.active-item.item-1 { /* CSS for the first item when hovered */ }
li.active-item.item-2 { /* CSS for the secpnd item when hovered */ }
```

**NOTE:** It doesn't hurt to make your CSS selectors more specific, adding an ID infront of those(say, the parent list ID) will help ensure you get less conflict with other competing styles.

I hope that's helpful.. ;)